# How to make a null safe condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the logic:

```
. . . WHERE hh.deleted = 0 OR hh.deleted IS NULL . . .
```

I want to make it more neat and short, so here is the new version:

```
. . . WHERE hh.deleted <=> 0 . . .
```

But the result is not the same .. Any idea why? and what's the different?

Comment: Perhaps you have other conditions that are affecting the result.

Comment: As others already answered your question, here is a possible solution: `COALESCE(hh.deleted, 0) = 0`

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same logic. Consider the following

```
deleted   deleted = 0 OR deleted IS NULL   deleted <=> 0
0         1                                1
1         0                                0
NULL      1                                0
```

The reason is that `<=>` simply returns 0 if one operand is `NULL` (rather than the `NULL` that `deleted = 0` would return if `deleted` was `NULL`), while `deleted IS NULL` will return 1 in that situation.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2d058f10c080b9c0da1dc4c4b2487fb)